# Concatenating Strings causing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing kind of weird issue in Python related to concatenating the strings.
We have a requirement where we need to connect to external data source through API and extract the data. While connecting through API we need to pass various credentials as part of raw_data in form of a string like below example (This is not actual credentials but use as an example).

```
raw_data = 'client_id=JWElPOC1XaR4NkldTaXsWGTzJsQ5FsO2DgHxTr&user_id=DFGRWSAQ&company_id=xyzComp&token_url=https://test.xyz.link.com/successfactors/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&private_key=FG2ASDDFFGJJHHmmdkfWqhdbd5cfsnvVDDGHHHBFGHSF3f6SDFFGHHGjD45dTG4sGHJddf6FG'
```

Below is the API command I am using to connect to the API

```
response = requests.get(url=api_url, headers=headers, data=**raw_data**)
```

Now when I am writing my code like this it is working without any issues. But when I am constructing the raw_data after retrieving the credentials from Secret Manager and saving to different variables and later concatenating to form a string it is not working.

```
client_id = secret["sf"]["client_id"]
company_id = secret["sf"]["company_id"]
user_id = secret["sf"]["user_id"]
private_key = secret["sf"]["private_key"]


raw_data = "'client_id={}&user_id={}&company_id={}&token_url={}&private_key={}'".format(client_id, user_id, company_id, token_url, private_key)
```

If I am Printing the raw_data variable after the concatenation it is showing exact same string but this way I am not able to connect.

Hence, I would like to understand if concatenation is using actual meaning of special characters in a string due to which it is causing issue.

I have used other ways of concatenating these variables and all are throwing same error.

Please advise.

Comment: I don't see any concatenation being performed here.

Comment: Your second string has extra quotes. Voting to close as typo

Comment: It actually fixed my issue. Since I was having single quotes as part of my postman command, I was explicitly adding it to my string as well while concatenating. Seems it is not required and after removing the extra quotes it start working. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** forming the same string, you have added extra single quotes:

```
 ↓                      ↓
"'client_id=...GHJddf6FG'"
```

You should most likely use:

```
raw_data = 'client_id={}&user_id={}&company_id={}&token_url={}&private_key={}'.format(client_id, user_id, company_id, token_url, private_key)
```

Comment: See I wasn't sure if that was the issue. Was a little gray to me. I definitely see how that's cause the issue

Comment: @Jab there might be something else, but I believe this is most likely the issue. Let's wait to get OP's feedback ;)